# How to change the name of .csv Response on Flask

Tags: python, csv, flask

I'm using flask for a web service and in some point I have to send a report to an user. It has to be on .csv format, I'm using this code:

```
# ...
def generate():
    head 'some headers'
    # some loops to get data from lists and dbs
    yield 'the data'
    # ...
return Response(generate(), mimetype = 'text/csv')
```

The name of this report is something like 'someletters.csv' and the user want another name more descriptive, how can I change the name of the report? I was looking for on Flask documentation and i didn't find anything useful.

Comment: You could temporarily duplicate the file with the new filename provided by the user, send the file, then remove the duplicate. Note you'll need to do the duplicate in a safe place to avoid any name clashes.

Comment: The problem with this is that the user press the button download, and then it execute the code. There is no way to modify the name?

Comment: Is the file stored locally or on the server side?

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following in your code:

```
filename_ = 'myfilename.csv'   # or any format you would like.
return Response(generate(), mimetype="text/csv", headers={"Content 
                disposition":"attachment; filename=" + filename_})
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add 'content-disposition' header.

```
    resp = flask.Response(...
    resp.headers["content-disposition"] = "attachment; filename=" + fileName
```

The most portable way of naming file is using the last part of request url i.e. `http://example.com/files/database_dump.csv`